# Capturing ctrl + left mouse click combination in javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, events, triggers, dom-events

I am trying to capture a combination of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keyboard button and left mouse click.
I investigated Google but have not yet found any solution.

Can someone help?

Comment: Event object from Click event has ``ctrlKey`` attribute which has boolean value whenever it was pressed or not.

Answer (score 4):

Check the ctrlKey attribute from the event. Example:

.html

```
<div (click)="clicked($event)">click me</div>
```

.ts

```
clicked(event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log(event.ctrlKey);
}
```

Check the [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-zjxudc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: FYI: If you replace `<div>` with `a` to make it tabable, you can get some simulate same thing with tabing on that a and CTRL + ENTER. Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ng8ncf

Comment: @Andurit great! Also, you could remove the javascript:void(0); com the href and just prevent the event (event.prevendDefault()) within the clicked(event) method.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the ctrlKet event property

```
<body (click)="click($event)"/>

click($event) {
    console.log($event)
    if (event.ctrlKey)
    {
     // logic here
    }
  }
```